# Filter out TZInfo:Timezone Ruby results to exclude

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to filter out the timezones TZInfo provides so I can exclude the values that are formatted like `(GMT +03:00) Nairobi` which are not compatible with the 95% of the locations there (Europe - Sofia, US - Central etc.).

```
<%= f.time_zone_select :system_locale, TZInfo::Timezone.all.sort, {}, {:class => 'ui fluid search dropdown'} %>
```

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Could you be more specific with what you want to achieve? It is not clear which timezones you want to filter out

Comment: @EmilianoDellaCasa As I describe, the 95% of locations follow the format "Continent - City" and only a small portion of them show as "(GMT +xx:xx) City"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
TZInfo::Timezone.all.select {|k| !k.name.include?("GMT")}
```

Comment: Just awesome, pure Ruby.